# Reducing electromagnetic interference in underwater acoustics cables

Tags: signal, electromagnetism, signal-integrity, crosstalk

Our college underwater robotics team has a passive acoustics system with four hydrophones that provide an analog signal typically between +/- 200 mV corresponding to the sound wave at that point in time. Our setup is as follows (per channel):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fODoDv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We have a hydrophone with a single-ended output connected to a bandpass filter with cutoff frequencies at around 15KHz and 50 KHz (our signals of interest are in the 25KHz-40KHz band). This signal is then passed through a waterproof connector to a digital oscilloscope inside our waterproof hull. Inside the hull that have multiple thruster cables that add significant noise to our acoustics signals, and we are attempting to mitigate that. Our current proposed solutions are, in increasing order of complexity.

- Wrap aluminum foil around the thruster and hydrophone wires
- Twist the ground wire for each channel around the signal wire
- Convert the signal to a twisted differential pair outside of the hull and convert to single-ended just before the oscilloscope
- Use a coaxial cable for the entire run (This would be very expensive for us as we would have to purchase coaxial waterproof connectors)

Besides the (ungrounded) aluminum foil, which did not seem to help much, these all will require significant teardowns in our configuration and are difficult to test.

Is there significant difference in electromagnetic interference rejection between using a twisted single-ended pair vs differential pair? What are other ways that we can increase our signal integrity in a cost-effective way?

Edit: Some more information on the system
The wires are roughly 3-4ft long in total run length. The hydrophones are [HTI 96-Min](http://www.hightechincusa.com/products/hydrophones/hti96min.html) hydrophones. Unfortunately I do not have the input/output impedance of it, as I don't know the exact specifications (They were donated 14 years ago). The filter is composed of a 2nd-order passive high-pass filter which we made out of two 22ohm resistors and two .1 uF capacitors, an [LTC1654](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1564fa.pdf) 8th-order low-pass filter configured to a cutoff frequency of 50KHz and with unity gain, and an [LTC6910](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6910fb.pdf) amplifier with a gain of 16. The oscilloscope is a [Picotech 2000a](https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/2000/picoscope-2000-overview) with an imput impedance of 200 kOhm/8 pF.

Comment: There is a lot more to know before we can help you. How long are the cables? What are the input and output impedances of hydrophone, filter and oscilloscope? What type of filter is this (electronic components)? Is the waterproof hull conducting so it can be used as a shield? ...

Comment: @StefanWyss I provided as much info as I have - I can measure the impedance of the filter circuit. I'm also studying computer science, so I apologize because I will have gaps in my understanding of electrical engineering

Comment: Looking at the data sheet of the Belden 9180 cable coming out of the HTI-96 'inline', that is a twisted wire 100% shielded cable, which suggests to me that maybe your hydrophone already has a differential output which may be converted to a 1 signal line with ground at the first connecter it encounters. The datasheet doesn't say how long the cable is.

Comment: @joeelectro We have spliced a shielded cable onto the hydrophone wire which goes up until the hull. The cable on the inside of the hull is just a wire-to-BNC adapter, and that is where we think the majority of the noise is being added. That portion of the run is about 6 inches

Comment: Some generalities: First, keep the entire cable shielded before amplification. Second, put an amplifier as close to the hydrophone as possible. Ideally, the amplifier could be *within* the hydrophone casing. Amplifier power can be derived from a DC connection through an inductor or resistor, with signal passing through a capacitor. That way, the signal piped inboard is at a higher level, overriding noise.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The filter/amp circuit will be placed as close to the hydrophones as we can get them, and will be powered off the same 9V line, split into +/- 4.5V. I'm now beginning to wonder if we have to be concerned about noise in the power lines

Comment: Lets convert that 2nd order HPF into a real 2nd order; the 22 ohms are interacting. Replace the 2nd with 220 ohm; and replace the 2nd capacitor with a 10X smaller cap.

Comment: I'd really like to confirm exactly how the spliced shielded cable is connected to the hydrophone wires. Are there 3 wires coming out of the hydrophone, to which you connected the cable? Which color goes where? Is it maybe coming differentially from the hydrophone but as a short cut 1 of the differential lines connected to the shield?

Comment: @joeelectro No, it's the 3-wire voltage one. One power, one ground, and one signal

Comment: This HTI—96 has a specified frequency range of 2-30kHz. Why do you think you can use it for the range of 25-50kHz?

Comment: What‘s the gain and fc setting of the LTC1654? BTW: Thanks for the additional edits/Infos. I think it would be best if you could also provide a complete schematic of the setup.

Comment: Sorry, just saw it: unity gain

Comment: @StefanWyss It's what we have. It picks up 40KHz signals (highest we need) high enough for it to work, and we're looking at finding new ones within our budget.